# Count DateDiff Exceeding A Specified Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL 2005 (I think), SQL Query Analyzer Version SQL 8.00.760.

I would like to write a query that returns a count into a Crystal Report from a table only if the due date exceeds 14 days based on the end date in the report search.  Based on my very limited understanding of SQL, I have come up with the following, which has proven to be wrong.  Please help me redo or refine this statement.

```
Select
   T.NextDueDate
From
   Task_ConditionAssessment T
  begin
     IF DATEDIFF(dd,T.NextDueDate,@enddate)>14
     Count(*)
  end
```

Again, this is not correct, but I am unsure what should be done differently....the error returned was Line 5: Incorrect syntax near 'count'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Task_ConditionAssessment T 
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,T.NextDueDate,@enddate) > 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Task_ConditionAssessment 
WHERE DATEADD(dd, 21, @enddate) > NextDueDate
```

This gives you how many tasks are after 14 days from @enddate.